# PHP - can't add objects into array

Tags: php, arrays, class

I've created a simple class:

```
class Event {


   var $a;
   var $b;
   var $c;


   function __construct($a, $b, $c) 
   {
      $this->a= $a;
      $this->b = $b;
      $this->c= $c;
   }



  }
```

Then I've created another class which extends Thread:

```
class WorkerThread extends Thread
{
    private $myUrl;
    private $eventsArr;
    private $counterDebug;
    private $postdata;

    public function __construct($myUrl, $postdata)
    {
        $this->myUrl = $myUrl;
        $this->postdata = $postdata;
        $this->eventsArr = array();
        $this->counterDebug=0;
    }

    public function run()
    {
          $flag=false;

          foreach ($json as $key => $value) {


                    $this->counterDebug++;
                    /* Death event */
                    $event= new Event($a, $b, $c);
                    array_push($this->eventsArr, $event);

                }
              }

            }
          }
          echo (count($this->eventsArr));
          echo (json_encode($event));
          echo ("\n" . $this->counterDebug);

    if($flag && count($this->events)>0){
    ...
```

When trying to add new created objects into the array, it stays empty.

What I've figured from debugging:

1) The objects are created.

2) neither eventsArr[]= $event, nor array_push are working.

3) I've set a counter that verifies the objects are being created and should be added to the array.

What am I doing wrong?

p.s-

I've removed **irrelevant** parts of code in order to simplify things.

Comment: i think you should create temp array which have all your events and then give it to $eventsArr

Comment: What problem were you trying to solve in PHP that you ended up using `pthreads`? They work fine but not needed that often? As an 'experiment' also good. Except you didn't allow any other pthreads  to run? pthreads have to give some result then `wait` until they get control back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you should create temp array which have all your events and then give it to $eventsArr like this.

```
$temp = array();
foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    $this->counterDebug++;
    /* Death event */
    $event= new Event($a, $b, $c);
    $temp[] = $event;
}
$this->eventsArr = $temp;
```

**OR**

```
foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    $this->counterDebug++;
    /* Death event */
    $event= new Event($a, $b, $c);
    $this->eventsArr[] = $event;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works :)
Could you please explain why it works only this way?

Comment: i think you should pass the array once to $eventsArr.

Comment: Please check the update of my answer. it will explain to you why eventsArr[] not worked with you.

Comment: I've tried the second option.. It doesn't work.. only the $temp works.. I still don't get what's wrong with the second option

Comment: can you please post your second option to let me check it

Comment: I meant your second option. the one without the $temp. I've tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98392/discussion-between-alaa-m-jaddou-and-mapisto).

Comment: i know what you meant i'm just asking to see your code with my second option